# Require.js build (r.js) with CDN jQuery isn't linking to the good jQuery path

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs, amd

I'm having a Backbone application using Require.js for AMD. I'm loading jQuery from Google CDN, but after build, the path to jQuery seems to be broken.

The build is happening without any trouble or error. But once I use the build version, jQuery is added to page using this URL:

http://example.com/assets/js/jquery.js

Instead of the CDN url. I feel this is due to the fact that my path config is lost and that require a dependency on "jquery" isn't taken as a reference to the path but as a normal call to a script.

Here's my main file:

**main.js**

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: '/assets/js/',
    paths: {
            use: 'libs/use-0.2.0.min',
            jquery: 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min',
            underscore: 'libs/underscore-1.3.1.min',
            backbone: 'libs/backbone-0.9.2.min'
},
    use: {
            'underscore': {
                    attach: '_'
            },
            'backbone': {
                    deps: ['use!underscore', 'jquery'],
                    attach: function(_, $) {
                            return Backbone;
                    }
            }
    }
});

require(['views/app'], function(AppView){
    var app_view = new AppView();
});
```

**app.build.js**

```
({
appDir: "../../www",
baseUrl: "assets/js",
dir: "../../build",
optimizeCss: "none",
optimize: "uglify",
findNestedDependencies: true,
preserveLicenseComments: false,
paths: {
    use: 'libs/use-0.2.0.min',
    jquery: 'empty:',
    underscore: 'libs/underscore-1.3.1.min',
    backbone: 'libs/backbone-0.9.2.min'
},
modules: [
    {
        name: "main",
        include: ["views/app"],
        exclude: ["jquery"]
    }
],
use: {
    'underscore': {
        attach: '_'
    },
    'backbone': {
        deps: ['use!underscore', 'jquery'],
        attach: function(_, $) {
            return Backbone;
        }
    }
}
})
```

(and I'm using use.js for loading non-AMD plugins)

Comment: After some more research, it appear that this behavior is caused by use.js

Comment: RequireJS 2.0 now ships with `shim` which does pretty much the same as use.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would first upgrade to the lastest RequireJS and check out this link:

[http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html#empty](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config)

And the notes on CDN in this section:

http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config

An example of a local fallback for `require.config( { paths : {} } )`:

> The above pattern for detecting a load failure, undef()ing a module, modifying paths and reloading is a common enough request that there is also a shorthand for it. The paths config allows array values:

```
requirejs.config( {
    // To get timely, correct error triggers in IE, 
    // force a define/shim exports check.
    enforceDefine : true,
    paths : {
        jquery : [
            '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min',
            //If the CDN location fails, load from this location
            'lib/jquery'
        ]
        // etc.
    }
} );
```

Comment: That's not exactly an answer to the question. But I've had no trouble with new projects using require.js 2.x series so for anyone else upgrading is probably a correct answer.

Comment: The first link now has a non existing answer. One of the reasons why questions should explain the solution here and not only link to external references... _sigh_